# why no need to add `extern` for external functions?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

below is my code:

```
//main.c
//I'm not using header file here,I know it is bad practice, it is just for demo purpose.

int main()
{
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

```
//test.c

void func()
{
   ...
}
```

we can see that above code compiles and can be linked by linker, but the same thing doesn't apply to variables as:

```
//main.c 

int main()
{
   sum += 1;
   return 0;
}
```

```
//test.c

int sum = 2020;
```

then this code won't compile and can't be linked, and we have to add `extern int sum;` before main function in main.c.

But why we don't need to add `extern` in `main.c` as:

```
//main.c 

extern void func(); //or `void func();` since functions are by default external
// without above line, it still compile

int main()
{
   func();
   return 0;
}
```

is it a little bit inconsistent here?

Note: by saying " Functions are by default external.",my understanding is: we can save some keystokes without typing `extern` , so void func(); ==  extern void func();, but we still need to add `void func();` before main function in main.c, isn't it?

Comment: _"we can see that above code compiles"_ are you sure about that?  It looks to me like `func()` is not declared in `main.c` anywhere.

Comment: @paddy it compiles with warning( not error,, so yeah it compiles, but for the variable thing, it compiles with error

Comment: C have implicitly declared functions, where the argument types where deduce from the call and the return type was `int`. If that deduction didn't match the actual function you had undefined behavior. A decent compiler should emit warnings about it, and you should always treat warnings as errors. See e.g. [this function call reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Function_call) for more details.

Comment: In your case the implicit function declaration (`int func(void)`) does *not* match the actual function (`void func(void)`) so you do indeed have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude where does `int func(void)` come from? I don't have it in my code

Comment: isnt last wxamle ub?

Comment: @amjad As you've noted, it compiles *with warnings*.  Do not ignore warnings.  C has a number of behaviors like this for backward compatibility with old C code before it was standardized.  The C standards committee, for better or worse, prefers to avoid breaking existing code.

Comment: `int func(void)` isn't in your code because it's *implicit*.  That's what *implicit* means.  You didn't declare it explicitly, so the compiler did it for you.

Comment: As I said, it's *implicitly* declared as such. The compiler creates that declaration for you.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes, for 'sum` , it is error:sum’ undeclared and for `func()`, it is warning:implicit declaration of function func1. if it's implicit as `int func(void)` and I'm using it as void return, then gcc should throw an error instead of warning, isn't it?

Comment: Remember that the compiler deals with separate [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). When it's compiling a source file it doesn't know anything at all about other source files or their contents.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so calling external function without using `extern void func()` compile, using external variable without `extern int sum;` does't compile, one compile while the other don't,  isn't it inconsistent?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the implicit declaration is `int func()`, not `int func(void)`

Comment: @amjad functions and variables are two different things, there is no reason to expect some arbitrary "consistency"

Answer (score 1):

Both programs are incorrect since C99 and may be rejected by the compiler. An identifier may not be used in an expression without previously being declared.

In C89 there was a rule that if you write something that resembles a function call, and the function name has not previously been declared, then the compiler inserts a function declaration `int f();` .  There was not a similar rule for use of other identifiers that aren't followed by parentheses.

Some compilers (depending on compiler flags) will, even if set to C99 or later mode, issue a diagnostic and then perform the C89 behaviour anyway.

Note: your program still causes undefined behaviour in C89 because the implicit declaration is `int func();` but the function definition has `void func()` which is incompatible type.

Comment: but he did not ask about it.

Comment: @P__J__: What did they not ask about? The body of the question asks why a declaration is not needed for a function identifier even though it is for an object identifier. This answer answers that. The title of the question is poorly worded, but the body makes it apparent.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't need to know anything about a function, in order to generate code to call it. In the absence of a prototype, it might generate the *wrong* code, but it can generate something (in principle, at least -- standards-compliance might forbid it by default). The compiler knows the calling convention for the platform -- it knows to put the function arguments onto the stack or into registers as required. It knows to write a symbol that the linker can later find and fix up, and so on.

But when you write "sum++", the compiler has no clue, lacking a declaration, how to generate code for that. It doesn't even know what kind of thing "sum" is. The code needed to increment a floating-point number will be completely different to that needed to increment an integer, and may be different from that needed to increment a pointer. The compiler doesn't need to know *where* "sum" is -- that's the linker's job -- but it needs to know *what* it is, to produce meaningful machine code.

Comment: "it knows to put the function arguments onto the stack or into registers as required" - this is not correct, e.g. the x64 ABI specifies that different registers are to be used for floating point parameters than integer parameters,  and variadic funtions have different treatment to non-variadic

Comment: With all due respect, you're mistaken -- at least for gcc. And, honestly, it only takes two minutes to check. At the point when the function call is generated, the compiler has to know the types of the arguments. The presence of a function prototype may cause these arguments to be treated differently, which is why the compiler might generate _incorrect_ code. But it can always generate _some_ code, so long as it knows the types. In many -- probably most -- cases the generated code will be correct. This is why, in many cases, you'll get the correct behaviour, even lacking a function prototype.

Answer (score -1):

> But we don't need to add extern for the function in main.c as extern void func(); or void func();(as functions are implicitly extern prefixed) and the code still compile?

That's correct. Functions are by default external.

To make functions specific to a local source file (translation unit), you need to specific `static` for them.

Variables, on the other hand, are visible in the source file only. If you want to make some variable visible outside the source file where it is defined, you need `extern` for it.

Comment: " Functions are by default external.", isn't that it just mean we can save some keystokes without typing 'extern` , so `void func(); ==  extern void func();`, but we still need to add `void func()` before main method, isn't it?

Comment: @amjad, 1) Yes, you can save keystrokes by leaving out `extern`, but using `extern` signals that it was intentional. A lot of people forget to use `static`. 2) C doesn't have objects, and thus it doesn't have methods. 3) It's not clear what you meant by the last bit. If you're talking about `main`, its correct return type is `int`. `void` is incorrect. If you're talking about functions in general, then `void` is necessary because `func(...` already means something else in the grammar

Comment: @ikegami I'm not talking about main method, I am just saying why we don't need to add `extern void func();` in main.c?

Comment: @amjad Again, there is no such thing as a "main method". A method is a function associated with a class and C has no classes. /// Because `extern` is the default. You never *need* to use `extern` on functions. But doing so makes your intentions clearer.

Comment: @ikegami, OK,main function is more appropriate to use. and yes we don't need to add `extern` before function, but at least we should have `void func();` before the main function

Comment: Variables declared at file-scope without the keyword `static` have external linkage , just the same as functions

Comment: @amjad ah, that's what you're saying. Yes, you should. It's customary to use a .h for that

Answer (score -1):

There are two completely different topics - function prototypes and linkage.

```
void foo(void);
```

provides the `extern` function prototype needed by compiler to know the number and type of parameters and the type of the return value. Function has an external linkage - ie can be accessed by other compilation units

```
static void foo(void);
```

provides the `static` function prototype. Function has an no external linkage - ie it cannot be accessed by other compilation units

By default functions have an external linkage.

Objects (global scope).

```
int x;
```

Defines the object `x` having the external linkage and type `int`.
If you define another `x` object in another compilation unit the linker will complain and emit an error.

```
extern int x;
```

Only declares the object `x` without defining it. The object `x` has to be defined in other compilation unit.

Comment: Silent DV-ter. Explain your DV.

Comment: (I'm not the DVer) "If you define another x object in another compilation unit the linker will complain and emit an error." - actually it is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required, and there is a common extension that no diagnostic is given so long as at most one of the `x` has an initializer, see C11 Annex J.5.11

Comment: @M.M Actually linker messages are not covered by the standard. All known to me implementations emit duplicate symbol when linking.

Comment: The linker is part of the implementation, and implementation message (insofaras whether or not they are required) are covered by the standard.  Which specifies that no message is required in this case

Comment: also, "Function has an no external linkage - ie it cannot be accessed by other compilation units" is incorrect. The function can still be accessed by other units, it is only the name identifier that cannot

Comment: @m.m can you call it without wrappers or another tricks - no. so it is not accessible

Comment: did you ever linked the program with duplicate external linkage objects? please show me the example.